# How to add children tree item after getting ajax response of tree value using vue-tree-list plugin

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, treeview

[image: Table data format]

I have table data format like above image

[image]

Expected tree view like above image

using [vue-tree-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tree-list) plugin

```js
<template>
  <div class="folder-tree">
    <button @click="addNode" class="d-none"></button>
    <vue-tree-list
      @click="onClick"
      @change-name="onChangeName"
      @delete-node="onDel"
      @add-node="onAddNode"
      :model="data"
      default-tree-node-name="New Folder"
      default-leaf-node-name="New File"
      v-bind:default-expanded="true"
    >
      <template v-slot:leafNameDisplay="slotProps">
        <span>
          {{ slotProps.model.name }}
          <span class="muted">#{{ slotProps.model.id }}</span>
          <button
            class="folder-actions-toggler"
            @click="toggleFolderActionMenu"
          >
            <i class="far fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </template>
      <!-- <span class="icon" slot="addLeafNodeIcon">＋</span> -->
      <span class="icon" slot="editNodeIcon">Rename</span>
      <span class="icon" slot="delNodeIcon">Delete</span>
      <span class="icon" slot="addTreeNodeIcon"
        ><span class="titu">New Subfolder</span></span
      >
      <!-- <span class="icon" slot="leafNodeIcon"><i class="fal fa-file"></i></span> -->
      <span class="icon" slot="treeNodeIcon"
        ><i class="fal fa-folder"></i
      ></span>
    </vue-tree-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueTreeList, Tree, TreeNode } from "vue-tree-list";
export default {
  components: {
    VueTreeList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newTree: {},
      data: new Tree([])
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onDel(node) {
      this.hideFolderMenu();
      node.remove();
    },

    onChangeName(params) {
      this.hideFolderMenu();
    },

    onAddNode(params) {
      this.hideFolderMenu();
    },

    onClick(params) {},

    addNode() {
      var node = new TreeNode({ name: "New Folder", isLeaf: false });
      if (!this.data.children) this.data.children = [];
      this.data.addChildren(node);
      this.hideFolderMenu();
    },

    getNewTree() {
      var vm = this;
      function _dfs(oldNode) {
        var newNode = {};

        for (var k in oldNode) {
          if (k !== "children" && k !== "parent") {
            newNode[k] = oldNode[k];
          }
        }

        if (oldNode.children && oldNode.children.length > 0) {
          newNode.children = [];
          for (var i = 0, len = oldNode.children.length; i < len; i++) {
            newNode.children.push(_dfs(oldNode.children[i]));
          }
        }
        return newNode;
      }

      vm.newTree = _dfs(vm.data);
    },
    toggleFolderActionMenu(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle(
        "active"
      );
    },
    hideFolderMenu() {
      const menuParent = document.querySelectorAll(".vtl-operation");
      [...menuParent].map((item) => {
        item.classList.remove("active");
      });
    },
    loadFolder(){
      this.axios.post("/templates/get-folders", {
          _token: document
            .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
            .getAttribute("content"),
      }).then((response) => {
        //Need to generate tree structure after getting ajax response 
        let node;
        for(let i = 0; i < response.data.folders.length; i++){
          node = new TreeNode({
             id: response.data.folders[i].id,
             name: response.data.folders[i].name,
             isLeaf: false
          });
          if (!this.data.children) this.data.children = [];
          this.data.addChildren(node);          
        }
        
      });
    },
    generateTree(list){
      var map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
      for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        map[list[i].id] = i;
        list[i].children = [];
      }      
      for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];
        if (node.template_folder_id) {
          list[map[node.template_folder_id]].children.push(node);
        } else {
          roots.push(node);
        }
      }
      return roots;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.hideFolderMenu);
    this.loadFolder();
  },
};
</script>
```

I have an ajax call to get the tree saved data from database. I can easily add parent node which is working but facing lack of resource how to add children along with parent node on the fly after getting response from ajax end. Any suggestion please?

Comment: just add `isLeaf: true,`  property to indicate it is a item not a folder

Comment: @KamleshPaul Seems not working. I don't need any leaf rather i always need folder inside another folder. It will be better if you could provide a short code snippets. Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far any loop ? and any try to create datastucture ?

Comment: Please see the function name loadFolder which is used to get response holds saved folders. Then i have added a loop to insert the folders to tree. this is just all are now as parent node but i need to add some of them as child node as those are sub folder of parent folder.